# Notify users with deactivated JavaScript that "secondary" functionality is missing?

Tags: tables, filter, javascript, sorting

On http://xmpp.org/xmpp-protocols/xmpp-extensions/ there is a table listing items with different statuses (active, obsolete, final, …).

When JavaScript is activated, there is a filter widget above the table (with pre-selected filters) as well as a sort functionality:

> [image]

When JavaScript is deactivated, there is no filter (all items are shown) and there is no sort functionality:

> [image]

Without question, it would be best if even users with deactivated JavaScript would be able to sort and filter the table (using GET forms). But let’s assume it is not possible here.

I wonder: **Should the no-JS variant include a note that the table would be filterable/sortable with JS?** And if so, how should it look like?

A short text note like "Activate JS to filter and sort the table."? Add the filter widget but [gray it out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayed_out)? Something else?

Or is this only a "bonus feature" so there is no need to notify users without JS that they are missing this functionality?

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest notifying the user at the top of the site/apps screen that some of the functionality is not available because JavaScript is disabled. The example below also includes a helpful like that can assist to [re-enable their JavaScript](http://www.enable-javascript.com/). I would also say that if JavaScript is not enabled on the browser, any controls that require JavaScript should be hidden by default.

[image]